# How to compile with all .jars in .m2 folder?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jar

my goal is to execute maven project xml using command prompt .I know we can execute by mvn clean test command or passing file name as argument to surefire plugin .but i don.t want to use maven command .

Like executing testNg.xml without maven

java -cp E:\Selenium\WorkSpace\VP_WS\TestNgProject\lib*;E:\Selenium\WorkSpace\VP_WS\TestNgProject\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

like here we compile all jar in lib folder same way i want to compile jar in ,m2 folder and run testNg.xml of maven project.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use [`dependency:build-classpath`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) to get the classpath.

Comment: Running unit tests is limited on your project ...which contains also all dependencies you need so I don't understand your intention here?